# This should be simple but want to do it right. CSS display:none; how to turn back on according to @media

Tags: css, mobile, screen, media

Hello I have css code that displays css div's according to screen size.

problem is that some browsers are not supporting the @media properly

so I want to turn off DIV's out of the box

```
.s2 {

display:none;

}
```

so how could I turn .s2 back on with this

```
@media handheld, screen and (max-width:769px) and (min-width:513px) {

.s2 {
display:????;
}

}
```

whould this work just fine and what is the default display property I need to set it back to? block?

Thanks for your help

Paul

Comment: Have you tried `block`? It ought to work.

Comment: you've answered your own question... Why not test your code first!

Comment: `display:initial`? Depends on what the element actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you want to display the item. You could use `display: block`, or `display: initial` if you want to display the divs initial state. More display options found here :http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Thanks display:block did what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The following property is default for DIVs :

```
display: block;
```